# Moderator policy regarding answer

Tags: discussion

Why a moderator deleted an [upvoted answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/108403/if-the-brain-cant-think-what-does) to a question?

Comment: Suggest removing the first sentence (“What's your problem?”) which could be easily misunderstood I think? But maybe the mod in question could weigh in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, while certainly raising valid points, it is rather a comment to the question, pointing out its flaws, than an attempt to answer it.

That is why it was *converted to a comment*. It was not deleted altogether.

Mind, while the standard for upvoted answers certainly is higher when it comes to deletion, it does not exactly exclude it.